# Returning success message with httpost in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I am making a call to an httpService for the purpose of posting data and want to display a message, for example if an error occured.

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular.module("adminSetup").controller("AccountController", ["$scope", "$location", "httpService", AccountController]);

function AccountController($scope, $location, httpService) {
    $scope.message = "";
    $scope.error = false;
    $scope.user = {
        username: '',
        password: '',
        firstname: '',
        lastname: '',
        email: '',
        city: ''
    }
    $scope.submitUser = function () {
        httpService.registerUser($scope.user,
            function (data) {
                $scope.message = data;
            },
            function (error)
            {
                $scope.message = error;
            });;
    }
}
})();
```

The service looks like this

```
(function () {
"use strict"
angular.module("common.services").factory("httpService", ["$q", "$http", "appSettings", userAccountHttp])


function userAccountHttp($q, $http, appSettings) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    var registerUser = function (user) {
        $http({
            url: appSettings.serverPath + "Account/Register/",
            method: "POST",
            data: user
        }).then(function (data) {
            return deferred.resolve("Success");
        },
        function (response) {
            return deferred.reject(response.data.exceptionMessage);
        })
    }
    return {
        registerUser: registerUser
    };
}
```

})();

As it is at the moment the Http Status message is not returned by the Service  to the AccountController. How can I 'return' the status back to the Controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to build a promise over a promise. just do this:

```
(function () {
"use strict"
angular.module("common.services").factory("httpService", ["$http", "appSettings", userAccountHttp])


function userAccountHttp($http, appSettings) {
    var registerUser = function (user) {
        return $http({
            url: appSettings.serverPath + "Account/Register/",
            method: "POST",
            data: user
        });
    }
    return {
        registerUser: registerUser
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem here is you're not returning the promise you can also take a look at [this](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)

```
(function () {
    "use strict"
    angular.module("common.services").factory("httpService", ["$q", "$http", "appSettings", userAccountHttp])


    function userAccountHttp($q, $http, appSettings) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        var registerUser = function (user) {
            $http({
                url: appSettings.serverPath + "Account/Register/",
                method: "POST",
                data: user
            }).then(function (data) {
                deferred.resolve("Success");
            },
                function (response) {
                    deferred.reject(response.data.exceptionMessage);
                })

            return deferred.promise;
        }
        return {
            registerUser: registerUser
        };
    }
})();
```